# adding content (link/image) into bootstrap 4 popover

Tags: html, laravel, bootstrap-4, popover

I am using bootstrap 4

I'm using this syntax in my code:

```
      <a class="btn popovers" href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="test content <a href='' title='test add link'>link on content</a>" data-original-title="test title">
        <div class="ui-bullet"></div>
        <strong>Booth 1</strong>
      </a>
```

but the `<a>` tag still showed like this:
[image]

is there anything wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `data-html="true"` on the pop over span.

This enables HTML content.

See more here: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/#options

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({html:true});
```